# Images looks low resolution and blur in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I notice that some of my images on website looks low resolution in Chrome and in Mozilla they looks fine.

Here are screenshots

In Chrome: 
[image]

In Mozilla:
[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

I found something like this, but it doesn't help

```
img {
     image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /*                     */
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox             */
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera               */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and Safari) */
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed       */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                */
}
```

This is how it look when I add image-rendering: pixelated;
[image]

Comment: Your links show the images in different sizes (apart from being behind an ad-wall), so it's difficult to compare. If you crop them to the relevant area and post them directly on stackoverflow, that would be a nice improvement.

Comment: I edited question. Take a look now.

Comment: If this image is in JPEG format then change to PNG, may be it helps you.

Comment: All images are in .png format.

Comment: your 1st & 3rd images are jpgs.

Comment: Please add some more details and some code. Are the images resized by the browser? What else are you doing to the images with CSS? If possible create a jsfiddle or StackOverflow snippet ( the <> button) with your code and images, make sure the images are somewhere publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome does some anti-aliasing. So, first, it might help to save the picture in the desired size (s.t. it shows correctly when you do not apply any sizing e.g. using CSS). Then, according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=crisp-edges), for Chrome the CSS should read `image-rendering: pixelated;` instead of <strike>`image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;`</strike> Note: Safari's values have changed as well and MS doesn't support it anymore/yet in Edge.

Comment: This make it worst. Take look at screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/463339/a13792d88c89af75739ecc87dd0af197

Comment: This screenshot has a different size again... when scaling bitmap formats, you can't expect perfect quality. As I said, try storing the image in native solution.

Comment: I edited my question so you can see how it looks when I use image-rendering: pixelated;

Comment: Try saving the pictures in the size they will be displayed and remove all image-rendering hints. E.g. the close icon (X) is 23x24 px but on the website it is somewhat larger (site's down for me now, so can't look it up).

Comment: I tried that first. Images looks like they aren't in same size as they are saved and should look. :(

Comment: The images are also skewed and un-skewed. I'd hope that this gets optimized away in the render pipeline, but then... who knows. I'd try starting with almost no CSS active and then add file by file.

Comment: Can you please take look at my website and try to figure am I doing something wrong http://motiongiraffx.com/services/ ? Click on menu icon at top left corner to see menu, and to see what I'm talking about, and compare with Mozilla how it should look?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

1 . Pulse "Ctrl + 0" (zero)
Its return to 100% web size.

2. No resize image with styles or width attribute. Design your image to the exact size you need.

Its works for me. ;)